# NSObject ModalView and Delegate

Tags: iphone, delegates, modalviewcontroller, nsobject

I'm modifying someone else's code and trying to use a ViewController however it is currently an NSObject. So below I have added `newDelegate`

```
@interface myAppDelegate : NSObject <UITableviewDelegate, newDelegate>
```

in my code I try to bringup a modalview with

```
[self presentModalViewController:newModalView animated:YES];
```

I get the error message `'myAppDelegate' may not respond to '-presentModalViewController:animated:'` that's fair enough, it is an NSObject. Can someone help me with a possible approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone wrote code with an `NSObject` as a `UIViewController`, you've got a lot of problems.  "Modifying someone else's code" means to me "I'm the new vendor after the old guy screwed it up so bad by lying to the client and SAYING they could do iPhone dev work".  Maybe go back to the client and say "we need to redevelop from scratch, this is garbage"? :)

As for the issue at hand - app delegates ARE NSObjects -- so that part looks right.  However, an app delegate should not usually be a `UITableViewDelegate`.  You'd have a window property and a rootViewController property in the app delegate, and the final call of `appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` would instantiate the view controller and load it into the window.  That view controller would then handle any views (and likely be the UITableViewDelegate in this case).

The `presentModalViewController:` code is built-in to UIViewController, so you're not going to be able to it to work directly from the app delegate.